How to add a custom theme with a custom authenticator in keycloak?
I am creating my custom authenticator for 2FA using SMS TOTP verifications in KEYCLOAK.
Here, I am showing mobile form and otp pages to the users to first enter the mobile number and then the otp that I am sending through sms via my custom auth.
My custom auth is working as expected.
Now I am trying to override the login pages with my custom theme, Here I am facing an issue in transferring data from my custom theme to my custom authenticator for further evaluations. Moreover, I am also not able to redirect the page to a new page once the user clicks on SUBMIT Button.
Some Code Samples are added below for better understanding:-
Custom Authenticator:-
public class SmsAuthenticator extends UsernameFormFactory implements Authenticator {

    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {


        AuthenticationSessionModel authSession = context.getAuthenticationSession();
        authSession.setAuthNote("formType", "mobile");
        context.challenge(context.form().createForm("mobile-form.ftl"));
    }

    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {

       // Code to send Otp
            authSession.removeAuthNote("formType");
            authSession.setAuthNote("formType", "otp");
            context.challenge(context.form().createForm("login-otp.ftl"));
    }

Below is my custom theme code for mobile-form.ftl
KCApp.tx

case "mobile-form.ftl": return <MobileForm {...{ kcContext, i18n,
Template, classes }} doUseDefaultCss={true} />;

MobileForm.tsx
<Template {...{ kcContext, i18n, doUseDefaultCss, classes }} headerNode={"Login with SMS"}>
            <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center">
                <form id="kc-sms-form" action={`/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?mobileNumber=${mobileNumber}`} method=post encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" className="w-full max-w-xs">
                    <div className={getClassName("kcFormGroupClass")}>
                        <label htmlFor="mobileNumber" className={getClassName("kcLabelClass")}>
                            Mobile Number
                        </label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="mobileNumber"
                            name="mobileNumber"
                            value={mobileNumber}
                            onChange={e => setMobileNumber(e.target.value)}
                            className="bg-[#E8E8E8] border-2 border-[#95C11F] rounded-lg p-4 w-full mb-5"
                            autoComplete="off"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className={getClassName("kcFormGroupClass")}>
                        <input
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn w-full text-white border-[2px] border-solid border-transparent p-4 rounded-lg overflow-hidden text-base hover:text-white"
                            value="Send SMS"
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Template>

Here after submitting I am able to get the call back to my authenticator code but I am not able to read the data entered by the user in this case 'mobile number'.
How can I do the same. Any guidance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
